# Search for email address in Suppression Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, suppressionlist

How can I search for a specific email address in a Suppression list within Marketing Cloud. Browsing the suppression list has no option to "Search" and I'd avoid exporting the whole list and searching using excel if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to search a normal suppression list or an auto-suppression list. The only way I can see is export to a file and search in csv or excel

Answer (score -2):

This is possible on All Subscribers list view. In Email studio go to **Subscribers > All Subscribers > Search Button**. Lookup your subscriber based on Email or SubscriberKey and when you open his/her record navigate to List tab. If record is member of Suppression, it will be visible there
[image]

Comment: I tried this, people that are definitely in a suppression list are not displayed in this view when then searching by subscriber key.